# Different function parameters for child classes

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a few classes-services that most of them share common code. So I created a parent class and they all inherit and override the functions when needed.

```
abstract class MyServiceBase<T>
    where T : class, IEntityBase, new()
{
    protected readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    protected MyServiceBase(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return _uow.GetRepository<T>().GetAll();
    }

    // more methods here needed for all the services that they are mostly the same for the subclasses but alot of them share the same problem
}

class AssetService : MyServiceBase<Asset>
{
    public AssetService(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow) { }
}
```

The problem comes when some services need more parameters to get the items.

```
class AssetCostService : MyServiceBase<AssetCost>
{
    public AssetCostService(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow) { }

    public virtual IEnumerable<AssetCost> GetAll(int asset)
    {
        return _uow.GetRepository<AssetCost>().GetAll();
    }
}
```

Now I can either not use the base class (MyServiceBase) or I will have multiple GetAll() for the same item. One way to work around it is to use `params` as parameters for the function.

```
abstract class MyServiceBase<T>
    where T : class, IEntityBase, new()
{
    protected readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    protected MyServiceBase(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll(params int[] parameters)
    {
        return _uow.GetRepository<T>().GetAll();
    }
}

class AssetService : MyServiceBase<Asset>
{
    public AssetService(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow) { }
}

class AssetCostService : MyServiceBase<AssetCost>
{
    public AssetCostService(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow) { }

    public override IEnumerable<AssetCost> GetAll(params int[] parameters)
    {
        if (parameters.Length != 1)
            throw new System.Exception("AssetId is not defined!");

        return _uow.GetRepository<AssetCost>().GetAll(i => i.AssetId == parameters[0]);
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that I have to remember which parameters are required and it gets very complicated if parameters are the same (e.g. int and string), some are optional, etc.

Is there any way I can achieve this type of inheritance, without duplicated code for each type of nesting or a nice way around it?

---

### Edit

As pointed in the comments, I might be trying to find a solution to a problem I wouldn't have if I used a strategy other than inheritance. So I'll try to explain why I went to that type of implementation and maybe somebody can point me to a different strategy for implementing the same thing.

My basic idea is to write a base class that does most of the things that all derived classes need. That way the derived class would not need to implement the same thing over and over and I can have minimal classes with Generics that they "automatically" have all the necessary functions.

For example an implementation of the Add() function that gets a DTO, adds it to the DB and returns the DTO back.

```
protected virtual ActionResult Put(TBaseDto dto, params int[] parameters)
{
    Initialize(parameters);

    TBase _i = GetSingleFromRepo(parameters);

    if (_i == null)
        throw new NotFoundException();

    UpdateChecks(dto, _i, parameters);

    MapDtoDataForEdit(dto, _i);

    ItemSpecificRules(dto, _i, false, parameters);

    SaveChanges();

    TBaseDto ret = _mapper.Map<TBaseDto>(_i);

    if (HasCustomMapping)
        CustomMapping(_i, ret);

    return ret;
}
```

And then have virtual functions for each call, so that child classes can implement their needs.

```
protected virtual void Initialize(params int[] parameters) { }
protected virtual void ItemSpecificRules(TBaseDto dto, TBase _new, bool isNew = false, params int[] parameters) { }
protected virtual void GetChecks(params int[] parameters) { }
protected virtual Base GetSingleFromRepo(params int[] parameters)
{
    return _repository.GetSingle(i => i.Id == parameters[0]);
}
protected bool HasCustomMapping { get; set; }
protected virtual void CustomMapping(TBase Base, TBaseDto Dto) { }
```

Likewise I have implementations for Get, Edit, Delete functions.

This type of implementation allows me to create some of my services just by inheriting the base and writing no additional code.

```
class AssetService : MyServiceBase<Asset>
{
    public AssetService(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow) { }
}
```

Most of them override only `ItemSpecificRules` and almost none of them overrides the `Add` method (only one from around 200 services).

Also when I need to change the `Add`, like adding a new check or something, I get to do it only once, in the Base (and the override, if needed).

Maybe my initial way of thinking led me to a dead end and I should change my strategy. I am restructuring my project either way, so I am open to suggestions!

Comment: Thought - You can look having predicate as parameter of the method.

Comment: Wouldn't that require for the user to write the predicate every time?

Comment: Yes, unless you add a overload of `GetAll()`, which could return everything (e.g., by supplying a predicate that always returns `true`).

Comment: But a bit more fundamentally, you need to ask yourself if such a generalization makes sense. If it does, go ahead and use it. Otherwise, don't even bother with inheritance for this method. It doesn't offer any abstraction or code sharing benefit as you would need to be aware of the implementation anyways.

Comment: It makes sense if you think a different method, like Add(). During Add() I always perform certain steps, like checking if user has permissions, map dto to proper item, do utme specific tasks, add it to database and save. I generalize the Add and calla virtual methods for the rest. But each of them fall into the same problem. Parameters generalization.

Comment: The Liskov substitution principle (stackoverflow.com/a/584732/8695782). I see it as: "only use inheritance when you want substitutability of implementations" or "you can't promise more or less than the base". I found that while some other SOLID principles can be negotiated/compromised against each other, this one leads to very weird issues in real cases when not respected. Inheriting Dog and Table from "FourLegged" is probably wrong. imho Decorator would only deepen the inheritance explosion. Work on refining your abstractions first, then maybe Strategy?

Comment: "I generalize the Add and calla virtual methods for the rest." Why though? If the methods aren't compatible with each other, what concrete benefit are you hoping to gain from virtual methods? Unless you're saying that you need to rely on child class behaviour as port of these generalized methods? In that case you're either going to have to push some responsibility to the child classes, or augment the types of base class (e.g., a GetParameters type parameter that implementations specify) or reach for a different tool. Inheritance and virtual methods are not the only way to share code.

Comment: I edited my post to add some more context about what I am trying to achieve and why I went that way. Maybe that helps identify the problem and not just trying to find a solution to something I wouldn't have if I didn't use this strategy.